# Why will my demo not write json to file using ajax and php?

Tags: php, json, apache, jquery, post

I am tearing my hair out of this one. I am only trying to teach myself php to do this one thing. Write a json file.

My php is probably a giant pile of dung, and more, was all over me with a 412 error. But moving it into the getJSON fixed that. My ajax call is somehow failing to feed the php my data, or my php function is not creating the file appropriately. Either way, I have an empty file

I wrote what was supposed to be an awesome proof of concept prototype, but as it is, the php portion or ajax call may be "made of fail". >__< Read on brethren, I wrote a simple demo.

I know it's silly to read a json file and then save a json file, but let me off on this technicality. Instead of having test.json, I have a servlet that gives me the json. I just save it in the javascript as javaobject. No sweat. But I tested it out as shown below:

demo.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Demo</title>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test1</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

test.json

```
{"herp":1,"derp":2,"supersuper":3,"derpderp":5}
```

test.js

var newData;

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON('test.json', function(data)
    {
        console.log('test1.js');
        console.log(data.herp);
        console.log(data.derp);
        console.log(data.supersuper);
        console.log(data.derpderp);
        //alert('success');
        newData = data;
        console.log(newData);


            $.ajax({
           type: 'POST', 
           url: 'json.php',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {"json":newData},
           data: {"json":JSON.stringify(newData)},
           success: function()
           {
          alert('Successful submission');
            },
           error: function(e)
            {
          alert("error" + e);
          console.log(this,arguments);
            }
      });

    });
});
```

json.php

```
<?php

    $json = $_POST['json'];
    $file = fopen('new_data.json', 'w+');
    fwrite($file, $json);
    fclose($file);


 ?>
```

I am running this on apache httpd. For example, I just fire up localhost/demo.html on chrome and I read the diagnostics. No matter what I do, new_data.json is empty. I even tried to just call the php file and have it write a file. No post. It didn't do anything. No matter what, when I check the apache server (or anywhere for that matter), there is no data being written to new_data.json. It's just not there.

[EDIT] I added in the ability to print an error message. There is something wrong with the php. It is returning an error and I am not quite sure what is going on, here is the message I am currently studying:

```
    Object {url: "json.php", type: "POST", isLocal: false, global: true, processData: true…}[Object, "parsererror", SyntaxError]
```

Please, can someone tell me what the heck I am doing wrong? I have stared at this for hours. I am willing to give rep, and if need be, take a ding on my own reputation on this, but I wouldn't ask unless I got desperate.

References
[PHP to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921520/writing-json-object-to-json-file-on-server),
[JSON Post to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931804/recording-a-json-post-to-file-using-php),
[Searched Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=write%20json%20to%20file%20php), and
[RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: you forgot to post the json.php file

Comment: in test.js your ajax call try change to `data: {"json":newData},` without this your $_POST array in php wont have a json key.

Comment: Still no success, but I updated my code to show this change. Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever is `check() function` do, hope it's `error less`

you should use `json encode` before `echo` in your `php page` like,

```
echo json_encode(array(check($_POST) ? 'true' : 'false'));
```

**Also,** trying to call `ajax` in `getjson callback` may solve your problem like,

```
var newData;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON('test.json', function(data){
        console.log('test1.js');
        console.log(data.herp);
        console.log(data.derp);
        console.log(data.supersuper);
        console.log(data.derpderp);
        //alert('success');
        newData = data;
        console.log(newData);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'json.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: newData,
            success: function()
            {
                alert('Successful submission');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That indeed did take care of the 412, thank you! I did originally have it in the get method. However, my file new_data.json is still empty. I really miss having a decent debugger for this. :( Thank you for your patience.