# why i cant send data to .json format file by ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, web

I'm making a simple server to send data to a .json file and receive that data from another page but I have problem how to store data in .json file

I used following code but it didn't work

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

     var _lname = "x";
    var _fname = "y";
    var _mname = "x";
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "data.json",
                data: "{'lastName':'" + _lname + "','firstName':'" + _fname + "','middleName':'" + _mname + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    }
                });

</script>
```

Comment: Is `data.json` a valid url ready to handle a `POST` request? Most probably no, so I guess that's the main problem here.

Comment: I'm new with JSON because of that I'm asking this question

Comment: That's fine. Your question is welcome here. I'm just pointing out what the issue may be.

Comment: thank you but i'm really confused about json

Comment: Ok, then this could be a good start: [What is JSON and why would I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383692/5640649)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply POSTing data to a JSON file won't work, as sending a POST request requires the server to listen for requests and do something with the payload you sent. You could make a simple NodeJS or [PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931804/recording-a-json-post-to-file-using-php) (or any other server-side language for that matter) that could handle saving the payload to a JSON-file.

Comment: you mean i receive data by PHP and after that save that data to .json file

Answer (score 0):

When you make a POST request, you send data to a web server.

The web server can do *something* with the data in the POST request.

By *default*, it does nothing. Imagine the problems that would be caused if anybody could make a POST request to anyone else's web server and write a new file to it. Google's homepage would be defaced every other second.

If you want to store the results of a POST request, then you need to write server-side code to do it (and you almost certainly will want to perform authentication and authorisation when you do so).

---

Note that the value of `data:` in your example code will *never* be valid JSON. Don't try to write JSON by mashing strings together. Use a library function like `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: you mean json is a method to help you send your data to server side easier

Comment: @Programmer — I didn't say that. JSON is just a data format. It is irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: i don't say data format , i mean a way to send data to server side

Comment: @Programmer — JSON is a data format even if you say it is not. The problem "servers won't write just anything you send them to arbitrary files selected by the client" is going to remain the same no matter what data format you use. Therefore your choice of data format is irrelevant to the problem.